# Stored procedure in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have one procedure in data base it returns list of objects when i try to iterate that result i am getting only one row multiple times.it is not ponting to next record in loop,

here is my code,

```
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("call getdata(?, ?, ?, ?)", Detail.class); 
List<Detail>  paymentAnalysisDetails=nativeQuery.getResultList();
for( Detail Details : paymentAnalysisDetails) {
    System.out.println(Details.getStart_date());
}
```

i getting output::

```
 start_date   end_date   total_no_of_txns 
 2015-01-01  2015-01-30                10 
 2015-01-01  2015-01-30                10
```

but while executing same procedure in mysql output as

```
start_date  end_date    total_no_of_txns
2015-01-01  2015-01-30  10
2015-02-01  2015-02-30  200
```

can anyone suggest me

Comment: JPA 2.1 has a dedicated API for stored procedure execution, so you don't hack the "native query" method. Maybe you should try that

Comment: any sample code for calling jpa stored procedure

Comment: Why don't you just use internet search for JPA2.1 documentation ?

Comment: I recommend this blog post about calling stored procedures from JPA 2.1: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need/have to call stored procedures from the 'createNativeQuery' method because JPA 2.1 supports them now. Check out the following code:

Stored prodcedure (MySQL):

```
DELIMITER $$
  CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getUsers(inputAge INT)
  BEGIN
    SELECT u.* FROM usertable u WHERE u.age >= inputAge;
  END;
$$
```

JPA calling:

```
int age = 10;

StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_getUsers", Usertable.class)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inputAge", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.setParameter("inputAge", age);

List<Usertable> userList = query.getResultList();
```